# Retrieving Dates more than Current Time in From Django Database

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, datetime, pytz

I am struggling to understand how the date queries work in Django as I am storing a database with train times. I want to get times that are greater than the current time.

The query looks like this, but returns zero results:

```
latestdepartures  = LatestDepartures.objects.filter(station=startstation,earliest__gte=timezone.now().astimezone(pytz.utc))
```

My database has the entry below for example.

[image]

When I run the query, I get the results below (first line is print(timezone.now().astimezone(pytz.utc)):

2020-08-01 15:49:06.610055+00:00
<QuerySet []>

The code which adds the data to the database looks like:

```
def convert_date_time(o):
    if isinstance(o, datetime):
        return o.__str__()


def updateservices(stationname,destination):
    now = datetime.now()

    # dd/mm/YY H:M:S
    datenow = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    board = DARWIN_SESH.get_station_board(stationname)
    stationdict = dict()
    stationdict['from'] = stationname
    stationdict['name'] = board.location_name
    stationdict['servicelist']=[]
    services = board.train_services

    for s in services:
        traindict = dict()
        service_details = DARWIN_SESH.get_service_details(s.service_id)
        traindict['departuretime'] = datetime.strptime(datenow + " " + service_details.std,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').astimezone(pytz.utc)
        traindict['callingpoints'] = []
        callingpoints = service_details.subsequent_calling_points
        for c in callingpoints:
            if c.crs == destination:
                callingpointdict = dict()
                callingpointdict['code'] = c.crs
                callingpointdict['name'] = c.location_name
                callingpointdict['arrivaltime'] = datetime.strptime(datenow + " " + c.st,'%m/%d/%Y %H:%M').astimezone(pytz.utc)
                traindict['callingpoints'].append(callingpointdict)
        if len(traindict['callingpoints']) > 0:
            stationdict['servicelist'].append(traindict)
    #For getting the minimum departure
    departures = [s['departuretime'] for s in stationdict['servicelist']]
    #Store the train departure object in the database
    stationdata = json.dumps(stationdict, default=convert_date_time)
    LatestDepartures.objects.create(
        station = stationname,
        earliest = min(departures),
        services = stationdata
    )
    return stationdata
```

servicedetails.std will be a time represented in 24hours in string format, for example "17:00".

Can anyone help, I am not sure if I am meant to change the date format somewhere or if it is to do with the way the datetime object is created by adding the time.

UPDATE:

Now storing the date in a different format as '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M':

Now I get dates that are greater than, but once the time current time has exceeded the earliest in the database, the query still returns results. Example output is:

```
2020-08-01 17:31:21.909052+00:00
print(timezone.now().astimezone(pytz.utc))
2020-08-01 18:03:00+00:00 - Time in database
```

Comment: Storing dates in the US format of MM/DD/YYYY is a bad idea, always. Use a standard format, typically ISO 8601.

Comment: I think that's it, many thanks. I was getting so bogged down with the timezone data and convinced it was to do with that, I failed to examine that line of code which is creating the date from strings.

Comment: Sounds good. Tell me if that helped resolve the problem and I will add an answer.

Comment: It's still not quite working because although the earliest time in the database is now less than the current time, it is returning results. I will put the output in the main edit.